# GTX 970 wont work with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics

Before marking as duplicate please read.

A lot of people seem to be having problems with the gtx 970 and Ubuntu. The posts are old though and just plain don't work with most using commands that don't exist anymore. I can't even so much as turn the computer on with the gtx 970 installed. It says noveau driver failed.

Every single one of the guides on the drivers brick my computer if they even work. Most just plain do nothing.

I've spent like 40 or so hours following all of these guides and it's pressing my patience to have to reinstall multiple times.

I just want something that works. Am I doomed to Windows 10? Do I have to get a new graphics card?

Comment: I actually managed to get it working in a really annoying way. I booted with no modeset. Installed the driver through the Ubuntu installer. Which usually leads to bricking the computer. Which it did when I tried to boot it. When I booted it a second time though it gives the options for booting. I used restore mode and after clicking through the first option for those it booted right. The problem is I have to do this every single time. So I still need a fix. Though at least it kind of works now.

Comment: Use Additional Drivers, select and apply the recommended version. Done! Doing anything else when one is completely clueless is asking for trouble. Rants such as this I read here several times a day and almost always the problem is nowhere else but between the chair and the keyboard.

Comment: There is a [known bug with GTX 970 that had 4 GB VRAM](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94990) that popped up in April 2016. It is supposed to be fixed now. The nVidia 384.98 driver works for me on GTX 970M w/3GB VRAM. Could you update your question with more hardware details?

Answer (score 0):

You will initially have to use the "nomodeset" to simply get into the installer / preview!  I have ONE monitor displaying correctly and working great.

Trouble is I have TWO 28" Samsung Monitors and the HDMI one is the only one working.  The Display Port monitor does not show anything, black screen, but Ubuntu THINKS it's working.

I used the Synaptics Package Manager to download and install the latest nvidia and then the system upgraded it one more time for me.  After all that I have a great looking screen, on ONE monitor, and even had to reduce the resolution because Ubuntu in 4K was just WAY too small for text and reading anything.

Still trying to figure out how to get the other monitor to show something, but it appears 16.04 and GTX-970 are not very compatible.  Merans I just might have to go back to Mint.  THAT works.  Mint 18.2 was working till it crashed and would not boot, so I thought I would try Ubuntu. Not such a good idea as it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standalone installer from NVIDIA, that can be used as a last resort:

- Download it directly from NVIDIA (link to the current driver: http://www.nvidia.de/download/driverResults.aspx/124219/de )
- put it on a USB stick or store it on the disk with a live system that works (or whatever works :)
- start recovery mode
- made the binary executable with: chmod +x Installer-File.sh
- start it with: ./Installer-File.sh

It once helped me, when there was no other working option for my GTX960M + Intel combo on 16.04 (or 16.10, not sure)